# jQuery toggleClass IE8 not working

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, toggleclass

I'm creating a plugin to replace checkboxes and it's working great on every browser but IE8 (I don't care about IE7 or IE6)

The problems becomes when I set the checkbox `selected` attribute with `toggleClass()`.
Is this a bug?

http://jsfiddle.net/amSdM/36/

Code: 
    $.fn.replaceCheckbox = function() {

```
    this.each(function(){

        if ($(this).val() !== '') { 
            $(this).attr('value', $(this).parent().text());
        }

        var checkbox = $(this);

            checkbox
                .hide()
                .removeAttr('checked')
                .before('<span>&nbsp;</span>')
                .click(function(){
                    $(this).prev('span').toggleClass('selected', checkbox.is(':checked'));
                });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $(this).attr('checked', true);
```

With

```
 $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Should do it :)

Comment: Really.. put an alert('x') before u update the attr and see if its getting reached

Comment: Nop, it's not working. It's so weird because the code works in every browser but IE. I uploaded a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/amSdM/14/. Select items in firefox or webkit and click the button and it will tell you how many options are selected. Try it in IE and you can't even select an option.

Comment: do you have a live version i could look at?

Comment: There's something going on because not even the button works in IE8. Button works fine in IE6 but the layout is obviously messed up.

Comment: ah, I'm on my macbook right now so I dont think I'll be any help.
what specific issue is happening right now with it

Comment: There must be something sensitive to IE8 in my code or a bug of some kind because Chrome works, Firefox works, Safari works, Opera works...